# Sending value of React checkbox as Boolean / Text to MongoDB database

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I have a React form which on submission I want to send the contents of a checkbox depending upon which one gets checked to my Mongo database.

At the moment, the rest of my form works fine, but I can't seem to get a value from my checkboxes - it just ignores it. When I submit the form, I get the following stored in my database - this is even if one of the checkboxes is checked:

```
checkbox1: ""
checkbox2: ""
```

Based off the following schema:

```
const SubmitSchema = new Schema ({
  checkbox1: String,
  checkbox2: String
});
```

I want the entries in my database to be like the following if one of the checkboxes is checked:

```
checkbox1: "checked"
checkbox2: ""
```

And vice versa. The contents doesn't matter just so long as I can distinguish it's been checked.

Worth noting I have other details added to the database on form submit, which all work great. They're not checkboxes though!

I've tried to do some research, but couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I figured that if I checked it using the state, the state would update to 'true' / 'checked' and therefore store in my database as 'true' / 'checked'.

Here's my code:

```
    class Form extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          toggleCheckbox1: false,
          toggleCheckbox2: false,
          checkbox1: '',
          checkbox2: '',
        }
    
        this.toggleCheckbox1 = this.toggleCheckbox1.bind(this);
        this.toggleCheckbox2 = this.toggleCheckbox2.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    
      }
    
      toggleCheckbox1 = () => {
        this.setState({
          checkbox1: !this.state.checkbox1,
          checkbox2: false
        })
      }
    
      toggleCheckbox2= () => {
        this.setState({
          checkbox2: !this.state.checkbox2,
          checkbox1: false
        })
      }
    
      onChange = (e) => {

        if(e.target.type === 'checkbox'){
     this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked})
   } else {
     this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
   }

      }
    
      onSubmit = () => {
    
        axios.post("/api/submitForm", {
          checkbox1: this.state.checkbox1,
          checkbox2: this.state.checkbox2,
        })
    
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
    
          <form className="form" method="POST" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    
            <div className="checkbox-container-2" onClick={this.toggleCheckbox1}>
              <input className="radio-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value={this.state.checkbox1} checked={this.state.checkbox1} onChange={this.onChange} />
              <p>Checkbox 1</p>
            </div>
    
            <div className="checkbox-container-2" onClick={this.toggleCheckbox2}>
              <input className="radio-input" type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value={this.state.checkbox2} checked={this.state.checkbox2} onChange={this.onChange} />
              <p>Checkbox 2</p>
            </div>
    
          </form>
```

I've tried to shorten my code down, but this is the bit that isn't working. Does anyone have any tips for how I could change my code to accept an output from my checkbox if it gets checked for both 1 and 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a checkbox the value doesn't represent the state, The current `true/false` is represented by `checked` property, So please modify your onChange function as below:

```
  onChange= (e) => {
    if(e.target.type === 'checkbox'){
      let checkboxValue = e.target.checked ? "checked": ""
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: checkboxValue})
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }
  }
```

Prevent Default behavoiur of form  on Submit action.

```
 onSubmit = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault()
     axios.post("/api/submitForm", {
         checkbox1: this.state.checkbox1,
         checkbox2: this.state.checkbox2,
       })
     .then(function (response) {
         console.log(response)
         })
    }
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for the response, but this unfortunately isn't working. Would I need to change my Mongoose Schema to reflect the checkbox? I've currently set it as 'Boolean' for the checkboxes.. I've also tried String. Boolean doesn't register anything, and String just returns an empty string. Any suggestions?

Comment: hiope you are doing e.preventDefault() too.

Comment: Thanks again for the response - still not working though. It's storing the values as an empty string. It's progress, but still not working. Any tips?

Comment: i'm not sure, what output you are expecting, may be you can give a rough idea, also i have updated step to console.log response as well, to see if the request is being send to database.

Comment: Hey - really appreciate the responses. I will update my original post to reflect what's happening and what I want to happen.

Comment: I've now updated the question to make it clearer, and provided schema / how it shows in my database. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have updated the onChange method, before setting the state we are setting the value to checked/"" based on checked property of the selected checkbox.

 If you want only one of the checkbox to be selected and other to have a value of "", Update the toggleCheckbox1 & toggleCheckbox2 values as "", instead of false

Comment: Hey - thanks for your help with this. Unfortunately your solution didn't solve it, but I've figured it out myself now. I've changed the state of the checkboxes to be the 'toggleCheckbox' instead. This returns true or an empty string if unchecked. Really appreciate your help as it's helped me figure out what was wrong though. Have a good day! :-)